# changing directory folder to all sub folders

Tags: batch-file, subdirectory

Hello i have a batch script but i cant work out how to change the path to scan all subfolders within the directory. 
In other words i dont want -
C:\Users\ally\Desktop\Documents\Table\CSV versions\2014\

but rather:
C:\Users\ally\Desktop\Documents\Table\CSV versions

as there are lots of different years of data in seperate folders.

Also to note within year folder there are month folders and within that there are the csv files.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "target=C:\Users\ally\Desktop\Documents\All"
cd /d "C:\Users\ally\Desktop\Documents\Table\CSV versions\2014\"
for /L %%a in (101,1,148) do (
    set num=%%a
    del "%target%\-!num:~-2!.csv" 2>nul
    >"%target%\-!num:~-2!.csv.txt" echo Type,angle,edge,Date,Frame,Sum,Mafe,Comp,Rim,Dose,Ell,Role
)

for %%a in (*.csv) do (
    for /f "skip=1 usebackq delims="  %%b in ("%%a") do (
        for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=-," %%c in ("%%b") do (
           set "line=%%c"
           if /i "!line:~0,2!"=="HH" >> "%target%\-%%d.csv.txt" echo %%b
        )
    )
)
ren "%target%\*.csv.txt" *.
pause
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To process every folder under the `All` tree then you can use a `for /d /r` loop and `pushd/popd` to set the current folder.

This assumes that every folder has the files you want to process.
Test this on a copy of your data and change the folder to point to it.

You seem to be deleting `.csv` files, creating `.csv.txt` files and then trying to process `*.csv` in the lower loop.  Should that be `*.csv.txt` ?

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /d /r "c:\Users\ally\Desktop\Documents\All" %%z in (*) do (
pushd "%%z"

for /L %%a in (101,1,148) do (
    set num=%%a
    del "-!num:~-2!.csv" 2>nul
    >"-!num:~-2!.csv.txt" echo Type,angle,edge,Date,Frame,Sum,Mafe,Comp,Rim,Dose,Ell,Role
)

for %%a in (*.csv) do (
    for /f "skip=1 usebackq delims="  %%b in ("%%a") do (
        for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=-," %%c in ("%%b") do (
           set "line=%%c"
           if /i "!line:~0,2!"=="HH" >> "-%%d.csv.txt" echo %%b
        )
    )
)
ren "*.csv.txt" *.

popd
)
pause
```

Comment: this is interesting and i would say has done the job, although the resultant csv files of each folder are in the monthly folders, is there anyway to put the resultant csv into 1 seperate folder?

Comment: change `"-%%d.csv.txt" echo %%b` to `"d:\my target\folder\-%%d.csv" echo %%b` if I understand the requirement.  Without seeing the files/folders it's a bit of a mystery.

Comment: Excellent this works, you understood perfectly. Many Thanks for your help just couldnt figure out the folders part

Comment: @ Foxidrive I have been using this lately however the code somehow puts csv files with just the heading into csv files at every sub level. I never looked at the sub level before until now (being offthe ball) Not sure why this is happening

Comment: Line 8 which starts with this `>"-!num:~-2!.csv.txt" echo ...` creates those files.  Are they supposed to go in your target folder too?   `>"d:\my target\folder\-!num:~-2!.csv.txt" echo ...` <-- Is that where they should be created like the comments above?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding another loop that will walk down the directory tree and if it finds a csv file, it will process it:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "target=C:\Users\ally\Desktop\Documents\All"

for /f "tokens=1* delims=" %%D in ('dir /s /b /o:-n /a:d "C:\Users\ally\Desktop\Documents\Table\CSV versions"') do (
    cd /d "%%~fD"
    if exist *.csv (
        for /L %%a in (101,1,148) do (
            set num=%%a
            del "%target%\-!num:~-2!.csv" 2>nul
            >"%target%\-!num:~-2!.csv.txt" echo Type,angle,edge,Date,Frame,Sum,Mafe,Comp,Rim,Dose,Ell,Role
        )

        for %%a in (*.csv) do (
            for /f "skip=1 usebackq delims="  %%b in ("%%a") do (
                for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=-," %%c in ("%%b") do (
                    set "line=%%c"
                    if /i "!line:~0,2!"=="HH" >> "%target%\-%%d.csv.txt" echo %%b
                )
            )
        )
        ren "%target%\*.csv.txt" *.
    )
)
pause
```

Explanation of the `dir` switches:

```
/s     - Displays files in specified directory and all subdirectories.
/b     - Uses bare format (no heading information or summary).
/o:in  - Lists the files in reverse order
/a:d   - Displays only folders
```

Explanation of the `%%~fD`: expands %A to a fully qualified path name (from `for /?`)

Comment: this only seems to work through the csv files in the 01 folder below the 2014 directory. It doesnt then then continue on to work through the 02 folder, 03 etc. 01,02,03 represents the months of 2014

Comment: I moved the rename command inside the loop, try it now.  Please note, I haven't tested any of the script

Comment: i dont think the script wants to play ball, getting the following in the dos window ' A duplicate file name exists, or the file cannot be found'

Comment: moved the ren command to the loop below still no luck but didnt get that duplicate message